# Wix learner: Confused between NETFRAMEWORK40FULL and DIRCA_CheckFX

Tags: wix

Both, I believe, check for .Net Framework installation. While writing wix xml do we need to have both, if yes why

Answer (score 2):

You do not need both, NETFRAMEWORK40FULL will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

DIRCA_CheckFX is the custom action used in Visual Studio setup projects to detect the NET Framework. If you have in fact migrated from VS to WiX you no longer need it.